# Cannot Connect to MySQL Port in AWS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our local PC cannot connect to MySQL of our AWS instance. Already done the steps mentioned in other stack questions, like setting bind-address to 0.0.0.0 (please see image #1), creating specific user (see image #2) and adding security rule in AWS to allow all connections (see image #3).

I have done anything I thought I could but still I cannot connect to MySQL remotely.

Image #1:

[image]

Image #2:

[image]

Image #3:

[image]

Image #4
[image]

Comment: Which error do you get? Can you connect to the instance but wrong username or password? Or have you checked with telnet the connection? 

`telnet yourip 3306`

Comment: I can't connect to 3306 port using telnet. :) @Stony

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your entries are correct and they look correct. Then you there are some possibilities.

1. Check if you can connect to the server with telnet `telnet yourip 3306` then you should get an result.
2. Check if have changed the correct security group. Perhaps that group isn't connected to your instance.
3. I think that should not be the problem but you should check your NACLs if you have some custom rules. Perhaps there is something blocking your connection.

So if you can connect to your MySQL but you can't login then you should check the permissions. And for MySQL changes don't forget to restart the MySQL service.

With `netstat -tulpen` you can check if the port is open.

Comment: for #1, I can't connect that's one of the reasons why I asked help here. :) ; for #2, yes it's connected to my instance :) ; for #3, iptables are off. And lastly, port is open (check image #4)

Comment: Do you have a local firewall that blocks your traffic? If you have a company firewall such ports are normally blocked.

Comment: I don't think it's the company firewall since we can connect to other server's 3306 port.

Comment: That you can connect to other Server has nothing to say if in that rules the target IP is included. Then you can connect to the target because they are explicitly opened.

Comment: I have checked with our firewall and port 3306 is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

sudo grep -R bind /etc/mysql

will show all bind configurations. There could be conflicting .conf file.